# The preposition with the word "settings"

Tags: prepositions

When I want to say someone to adjust something *in the settings* (e.g. of some application), is preposition *"in"* will be correct?

I am confused with prepositions with the "settings", because I am not sure whether it is appropriate to put preposition *in, at, on* or *through*.

Please, assist me what is the proper one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say either.

> Make this adjustment in Settings.
>
> Make this adjustment in the settings of the phone.
>
> Make this adjustment in the phone settings.
>
> You can adjust the volume setting.

"Settings" is a label for that aspect or section of the phone's configuration, and no article is needed when referring to something by its label.

> Coffee machines are found in aisle 3 *in Appliances*.

But when referring to the settings themselves, it is a normal noun, and requires an article like other count-nouns.

P.S. With respect to the preposition, you can say

> ... in the settings

or

> ... to the settings

P.P.S. And although "settings of the software" or "settings of the phone" are perfectly grammatical, it is more typical to use a noun adjunct there, at least in documentation or instructions:

> ... in the software settings
>
> ... in the phone settings

Comment: And if we talk about prepositions, not articles? Is it okay to say *"in the settings"*?

Comment: @Gamilato: please see the P.S.

Answer (score 0):

An application has settings:

You adjust its settings. You do not adjust anything in its settings.

- Adjust visual settings
- Adjust microphone settings
- Adjust browser settings
- Adjust Windows settings
- Adjust settings for [whatever]

etc.

Comment: I see, but if by settings I mean the Settings section of the some software interface. Like *"choose the webcam in settings of the software"*. Is it correct?

Comment: I need abstract directions because it is unknown what the software will use the person that will read this instruction. Also why are you so differ with Tᴚoɯɐuo over this topic?

Comment: @Gamilato: Lambie is just plain wrong about **in settings**.  The preposition **in** has been used with settings for over 100 years. See the electrical examples here from 1915. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22changes%20in%20the%20settings%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Please be careful with your comments and do not attribute to me what I did not say.

Comment: @Lambie: "You do not adjust anything in its settings."  Your words.

Comment: Those are "his" words: "adjust something in the settings" (e.g. of some application). Generally, in manuals or informational writing, you would not say that. I guess it could be in a dialogue.